Is this a valid assumption in calculating $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\cot(x)dx$
I was doing the integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\cot(x)dx$ when i came upon an issue with  a limit, and i am unsure if my resolution to it is mathematically sound. my working up to that point is as follows:
$$Let\;I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\cot(x)dx,\;Let\;u = x,\;dv = \cot(x)dx$$
$${\Rightarrow}\;du = dx,\;v = \int\cot(x)dx = \ln(\sin(x))$$
$$I = [x\ln(\sin(x))]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} - \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin(x))dx. let\;J = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin(x))dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{a}f(x-a)dx\;{\Rightarrow}\;J = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x))dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\cos(x))dx$$
$$\therefore\; 2J = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin(x))dx+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\cos(x))dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin(x)\cos(x))dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\frac{\sin(2x)}{2})dx$$
$$= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin(2x))dx-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(2)dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin(2x))dx-\frac{\pi\ln(2)}{2}$$
$$Let\;\phi=2x\;{\Rightarrow}\;dx=\frac{1}{2}d\phi$$
$$2J =\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}ln(sin(\phi))d\phi-\frac{\pi\ln(2)}{2}$$
$\sin(\pi-x)=\sin(x)\;{\Rightarrow}\;\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}ln(sin(\phi))d\phi=2(\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}ln(sin(\phi))d\phi)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}ln(sin(\phi))d\phi$
$$\therefore\;2J=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}ln(sin(\phi))d\phi-\frac{\pi\ln(2)}{2}=J-\frac{\pi\ln(2)}{2}$$
$$\therefore\;J=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin(x))dx=-\frac{\pi\ln(2)}{2}$$
$${\Rightarrow}\;\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\cot(x)dx=[x\ln(\sin(x))]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-(-\frac{\pi\ln(2)}{2})=\frac{\pi\ln(2)}{2}+[x\ln(\sin(x))]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
$$$$
This is where my issue arises. this limit only exists if the bottom bound is tending towards $0$ from above. $\lim_{x\to0^+}[x\ln(\sin(x))]=0$, but $\lim_{x\to0}[x\ln(\sin(x))]$ does not exist, since $\lim_{x\to0^-}[x\ln(\sin(x))]$ is undefined. Is it mathematically sound to simply evaluate the limit as $x\to0^+$ with the reasoning that it is implied by the existence of the original integral itself since the integrand is undefined at x=$0$?

Your integral does not involve negative values of $x$, so the left-hand limit has no relevance here. So, yes, you can take the right-hand limit to finish your computation.

Thank you for the answer. I assumed that the values would always be tended towards from 'inside' the integral, which i think is correct. I.e. the bottom bound will take the right hand limit, and the upper bound will take the left hand limit

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x \cot x d x 
= & \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x \cos x}{\sin x} d x \\
= & \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x d(\ln (\sin x)) \\
= & {[x \ln (\sin x)]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (\sin x) d x } \\
= & 0-\left(-\frac{\pi}{2} \ln 2\right) \\
= & \frac{\pi}{2} \ln 2
\end{aligned}
$$

My question was about an assumption that makes the evaluation of the limit of $\lim_{x\to0}[x\ln(\sin(x))]$ possible to evaluate, which your answer avoids by not showing how you computed the limit

Since the domain of the integrand $x\ln(\sin x)$ is $(0, \infty)$, therefore we take the limit as $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}
x\ln(\sin x)$

That was basically what I was asking in the initial question. Thank you for the response
